# Refactor a (multi)generator python function

Tags: python, refactoring, generator

I am looking for a pythonic way to further refactor the function `event_stream()` below. This simplified and abstracted from a python flask web app I am writing to experiment with python.

The function is a generator, with an endless loop checking a number of objects (currently implemented as dicts) for changes (made elsewhere in the application).

If an object has changed, an event is yielded, which the caller function `sse_request()` will then use to create a server-side-event.

```
def event_stream():
    parrot_old = parrot.copy()
    grail_old = grail.copy()
    walk_old = walk.copy()
    while True:
        print("change poller loop")
        gevent.sleep(0.5)

        parrot_changed, parrot_old = check_parrot(parrot_new=parrot, parrot_old=parrot_old)
        if parrot_changed:
            yield parrot_event(parrot)

        grail_changed, grail_old = check_grail(grail_new=grail, grail_old=grail_old)
        if grail_changed:
            yield grail_event(grail)

        walk_changed, walk_old = check_walk(walk_new=walk, walk_old=walk_old)
        if walk_changed:
            yield walk_event(walk)


@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

While event_stream() is currently short enough to be readable, it breaks the concept of doing "one only, and do that well",
because it is tracking changes to three different objects. If I was to add further objects to track
(e.g. an "inquisitor", or a "brain") it would become unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer:

---

Two steps of refactoring have been applied to the function `event_stream()`. These are explained in chronological order in the “Long Answer” below, and in summary here:

The original function had multiple yields: one per “object” whose changes are to be tracked. Adding further objects implied adding further yields.

- In the first refactoring this was eliminated by looping through a structure storing the objects to be tracked.
- In the second refactoring changing the “objects” from dicts to instances of real objects. This allowed the storage structure and the loop to become radically simpler. The "old copies" and the functions used to spot changes and create the resulting server-side-events could be moved into the objects.

The fully refactored code is at the bottom of the "Long Answer".

### Long Answer, Step by Step:

---

### First Refactor:

Below I have pasted my first refactoring, inspired by **jgr0**'s answer.
His initial suggestion did not work straight away, because it used a dict as a dict key; but keys must be hashable (which dicts are not).
It looks like we both hit on using a string as key, and moving the object/dict to an attribute in parallel.

This solution works where the "object" is either a dict, or a list of dicts (hence use of `deepcopy()`).

Each object has a "checker" function to check if it has changed (e.g check_parrot), 
and an "event" function (e.g. parrot_event) to build the event to be yielded.

Additional arguments can be configured for the xxx_event() functions via the "args" attribute, which is passed as *args.

The objects in `copies{}` are fixed at the time of copying, while those in configured in `change_objects{}` are references, and thus reflect the latest state of the objects. Comparing the two allows changes to be identified.

While the `event_stream()` function is now arguably less readable than my original, 
I no longer need to touch it to track the changes of further objects. These are added to `change_objects{}`.

```
# dictionary of objects whose changes should be tracked by event_stream()
change_objects = {
    "parrot": {
        "object": parrot,
        "checker": check_parrot,
        "event": parrot_event,
        "args": (walk['sillyness'],),
            },
    "grail": {
        "object": grail,
        "checker": check_grail,
        "event": grail_event,
    },
    "walk": {
        "object": walk,
        "checker": check_walk,
        "event": walk_event,       
    },
}

def event_stream(change_objects):
    copies = {}
    for key, value in change_objects.items():
        copies[key] = {"obj_old": deepcopy(value["object"])}  # ensure a true copy, not a reference!

    while True:
        print("change poller loop")
        gevent.sleep(0.5)
        for key, value in change_objects.items():
            obj_new = deepcopy(value["object"]) # use same version in check and yield functions
            obj_changed, copies[key]["obj_old"] = value["checker"](obj_new, copies[key]["obj_old"])
            if (obj_changed): # handle additional arguments to the event function
                if "args" in value:
                    args = value["args"]
                    yield value["event"](obj_new, *args)
                else:
                    yield value["event"](obj_new)


@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(change_objects),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

### Edit: Second Refactor, using Objects instead of Dicts:

If I use objects rather than the original dicts:

- The change-identification and event-building methods can be moved
  into the objects.
- The objects can also store the "old" state.

Everything becomes simpler and even more readable: `event_stream()` no longer needs a `copies{}` dict (so it has only one structure to loop over), and the `change_objects{}` is now a simple list of tracker objects:

```
def event_stream(change_objects):
    while True:
        print("change poller loop")
        gevent.sleep(0.5)
        for obj in change_objects:
            if obj.changed():
                yield obj.sse_event()

@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    # List of objects whose changes are tracked by event_stream
    # This list is in sse_request, so each client has a 'private' copy
    change_objects = [
        ParrotTracker(),
        GrailTracker(),
        WalkTracker(),
        ...
        SpamTracker(),
    ]
    return Response(
            event_stream(change_objects),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

An example tracker class is:

```
from data.parrot import parrot
class ParrotTracker:

    def __init__(self):
        self.old = deepcopy(parrot)
        self.new = parrot

    def sse_event(self):
        data = self.new.copy()
        data['type'] = 'parrotchange'
        data = json.dumps(data)
        return "data: {}\n\n".format(data)

    def truecopy(self, orig):
        return deepcopy(orig) # ensure is a copy, not a reference

    def changed(self):
        if self.new != self.old:
            self.old = self.truecopy(self.new)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I think it now smells much better!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a dict mapping your objects to the change detector function?

It may be something like this:

```
object_change_checker_events = {
    parrot: {
                "checker": check_parrot, 
                "event": parrot_event
            },
    //grail : ................
    .................
}


def event_stream(object_change_checker_events):
    copies = {}
    for obj in object_change_checker_events:
        copies[obj] = obj.copy())
    while True:
        print("change poller loop")
        gevent.sleep(0.5)

        for obj in copies:
            obj_changed, obj_old = object_change_checker_events[obj]["checker"](obj, copies[obj]
            if(obj_changed):
                yield object_change_checker_events[obj]["event"](obj)
```

Your main job here will be to construct the **object_change_checker_events** dictionary.

I have changed the structure of the dictionary. Try this:

```
object_change_checker_events = {

    'parrot': {
                "object": parrot
                "checker": check_parrot, 
                "event": parrot_event
            },
    //grail : ................
    .................
}


def event_stream(object_change_checker_events):
    copies = {}

    for obj in object_change_checker_events:
        copies[obj] = {
            "old": obj["object"].copy(),
            "new": obj["object"]
        }

    while True:
        print("change poller loop")
        gevent.sleep(0.5)

        for obj in copies:
            obj_changed, obj_old = object_change_checker_events[obj]["checker"](copies[obj]["new"], copies[obj]["old"])
            if(obj_changed):
                yield object_change_checker_events[obj]["event"](obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer. I think you have a closing bracket too many on `obj.copy())`, and one missing on  `(obj, copies[obj]`. I will get back to you once I have tested in my own code.

Comment: I am getting **TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'** on the line `"event": parrot_event` ... I must sleep on it.

Comment: This won’t work without a tweak that so far has escaped me! _parrot_, _walk_ etc. are **Dicts** —> mutable —> not hashable —> cannot be used as keys in a Dict. `frozenset(parrot.items()): {...}` will run, but defeats the purpose: my objects change!

Comment: With a rejigged mapping: `object_change_checker_events = {
    "parrot": {
                "obj_old": parrot,
                "checker": check_parrot,
                "event": parrot_event
            },
}` i.e. the main key is a string, and the equivalent dict is now a value, then I have a version this solution that works (subject to more testing)

Comment: looks like we both hit on broadly similar solutions in parallel, I will mine shortly as answer.

Comment: Another good way would be to have a class containing these attributes, and creating custom objects depending on the type. That would be a good OOP based approach I guess.

Comment: I agree, classes are a logical next step up from my simple dicts. parrot, grail etc could become classes with check and event methods (using some kind of interface, abc, mixin ....). One thing at a time!