# Server-sent-events not received by all web-clients

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

I have a Flask web-server which generates server-sent-events (sse) which should be received by all connected web-clients.

In "**Version 1**" below this works. All web-clients receive the events, and update accordingly.

In "**Version 2**" below, which is a refactoring of Version 1, this no longer works as expected:

Instead I get:

- mostly only one of the web-clients gets the event, or
- rarely
  multiple web-clients get the event, or
- rarely none of the
  web-clients get the event

As far as I can make out, the server is always generating the events, and normally at least one client is receiving.

My initial test hosted the web-server on a Raspberry Pi 3, with the web-clients on the Pi, on Windows and OSX using a variety of browsers.

To eliminate any possible network issues I repeated the same test with the web-server and 3 instances of Chrome all hosted on the same OSX laptop.
This gave the same results: Version 1 "OK", Version 2 "NOT OK".

The client that successfully receives seemingly varies randomly from event to event: so far I can't discern a pattern.

Both Version 1 and Version 2 have a structure `change_objects` containing "things that should be tracked for changes"

- In Version 1 `change_objects` is a dict of dicts.
- In Version 2 I refactored `change_objects` to be a list of instances of the class `Reporter`, or sub classes of `Reporter`.

The changes to the "things" are triggered based on web-services received elsewhere in the code.

### Version 1 (OK: sse events received by all web-clients)

```
def check_walk(walk_new, walk_old):
    if walk_new != walk_old:
        print("walk change", walk_old, walk_new)
        return True, walk_new
    else:
        return False, walk_old

def walk_event(walk):
    silliness = walk['silliness']
    data = '{{"type": "walk_change", "silliness": {}}}'.format(silliness)
    return "data: {}\n\n".format(data)

change_objects = {
    "walk1": {
        "object": walks[0],
        "checker": check_walk,
        "event": walk_event,
    },
    ... more things to be tracked...
}

def event_stream(change_objects):
    copies = {}
    for key, value in change_objects.items():
        copies[key] = {"obj_old": deepcopy(value["object"])}  # ensure a true copy, not a reference!

    while True:
        gevent.sleep(0.5)
        for key, value in change_objects.items():
            obj_new = deepcopy(value["object"]) # use same version in check and yield functions
            obj_changed, copies[key]["obj_old"] = value["checker"](obj_new, copies[key]["obj_old"])
            if (obj_changed):
                yield value["event"](obj_new)

@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(change_objects),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

### Version 2 (NOT OK: sse events NOT always received by all web-clients)

```
class Reporter:

    def __init__(self, reportee, name):
        self._setup(reportee, name)

    def _setup(self, reportee, name):
        self.old = self.truecopy(reportee)
        self.new = reportee
        self.name = "{}_change".format(name)

    def truecopy(self, orig):
        return deepcopy(orig)

    def changed(self):
        if self.new != self.old:
            self.old = self.truecopy(self.new)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def sse_event(self):
        data = self.new.copy()
        data['type'] = self.name
        data = json.dumps(data)
        return "data: {}\n\n".format(data)

class WalkReporter(Reporter):

    # as we are only interested in changes to attribute "silliness" (not other attributes) --> override superclass sse_event
    def sse_event(self): 
        silliness = self.new['silliness']
        data = '{{"type": "walk_change", "silliness": {}}}'.format(silliness)
        return "data: {}\n\n".format(data)

change_objects = [
    WalkReporter(name="walk1", reportee=walks[0]),
    ... more objects to be tracked...
] 

def event_stream(change_objects):
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(0.5)
        for obj in change_objects:
            if obj.changed():
                yield obj.sse_event()

@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(change_objects),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Full disclosure: This question is a follow on to the question: [Refactor a (multi)generator python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814896/refactor-a-multigenerator-python-function/38831039#38831039)
which focussed on refactoring the `event_stream()` function when tracking changes to multiple "things".
However the problem here is clearly outside the scope of the original question, hence a new one.

Comment: After lots of debugging it has just clicked: this is a concurrency / timing problem. I seem to have a solution, but need to do a little more testing before posting an answer / explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refactored "Version 2" code in the question suffers from a concurrency / timing problem.

`sse_request()` is called for each of the web-clients  (in the test case 3 instances). We thus have 3 instances looping in `event_stream()`.

These calls happen "more or less" in parallel: which actually means in random sequence.

However the list `change_objects` is shared, so the first web-client that spots a change will update the "old" copy in the shared `WalkReporter` instance to the latest state, and may do so before the other clients spot the change. i.e. the first successful web-client effectively hides the change from the other web-clients.

This is easily fixed, by giving each web-client its own copy of `change_objects`.

i.e. `change_objects` is moved into `sse_request()` as shown below.

```
@app.route('/server_events')
def sse_request():
    change_objects = [
        WalkReporter(name="walk1", reportee=walks[0]),
        ... more objects to be tracked...
    ]
    return Response(
            event_stream(change_objects),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

With this minor change, each instance of `sse_request()` can spot the changes, and thus all the web-clients receive the sse-events as expected.